# how to declare global array in JavaScript, initialize it's value once and use it's value at multiple places/functions

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a functionality in which I need to populate array dynamically once per request and access that array's values(populated one) at different places:

```
let addresses = [];
let countries = [];
let streetAddresses = [];



const streetAddressInputElement = document.querySelector("#street");
const resultWrapper = document.querySelector(".results");
const searchWrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");


function getAddresses() {

  var requestData = {
    "reqHeader": {
      "reqID": "",
      "sessionID": ""
    }
    }
  };
  var settings = {        "url":"https://devapi.sample.com/AddressManagement/v2/Recognition/qa",
    "method": "POST",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "data": JSON.stringify(requestData),
  };
  $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    addresses = response.addressManagementResponseV2.addressManagementResponseData;
    streetAddresses = addresses.map((x) => x.streetAddress);
  });
  
}
```

//function call

```
 getAddresses()

function loadData(data) {
  if (!data.length) {
    return searchWrapper.classList.remove("show");
  }

  let content = data.map((item) => {
    return `<li class='suggestItem'>${item}</li>`
  }).join('');
  searchWrapper.classList.add("show");
  resultWrapper.innerHTML = `<ul class='ulists' id='uid'>${content}</ul>`;
} 
//Listener for input text
streetAddressInputElement.addEventListener("input", function () {
  if(!streetAddressInputElement.value.length)
  {
     hideResultDiv();
  }
  const filteredData = filterData(streetAddresses,streetAddressInputElement.value);
  loadData(filteredData)
});

const listval=document.querySelector('.results');
listval.addEventListener("click",function(e){
  $('#street').val(e.path[0].innerText);
  hideResultDiv();
});

function onButtonSubmit()
{
// In this functtion I want to perform operation on "addresses" array 
//but here I'm getting the empty array

}
```

I don't know what I'm missing, I'm very new to javascript so not aware of the scope of the data.
I mean I'm not loading the entire page while onSubmit method, so expecting that I should be able to access the data of above populated arrays.
I have provided all the details related to this hoping now I am more clear now.

Comment: You need more details. With your current vague snippet, this is not reproducible: `let arr = []; function initArr() { arr = [1, 2, 3] }; initArr(); console.log(arr)` will output `[1, 2, 3]` as expected.

Comment: @LMD I have provided the details now

Comment: Then gagz's answer is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

API call is async and response from API call can take time to actually be fetched that's why your array is empty when you try to access it somewhere else in the code.

What you can use is `async/await` or `then` approach. Here's more info about it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises